# Check download/upload speed but using external IP address

Tags: networking, ip

Is there any utility that checks the download speed and the upload speed that an external IP address offers? I tried iftop but it will not install using brew on my Mac. I need to check what is the maximum download speed and upload speed an external server can provide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do something like this (if you don't have access to server and if you are not able to install anything there).

You can always try to send something to server (to check it's upload speed) or try to download something (to check download speed).

Anyway I wouldn't relay on this method. Since you don't know load of the server (how many users are downloading/uploading something) it will be very inaccurate guess. What is more you are limited by your own downloading/uploading speed limit and in most cases those limits are much bigger than server limits.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something called NetAcuity by Digital Element can do this, albeit at a high price. According to the their [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Element):

> NetAcuity uncovers geographic information, connection speed, domain name, Internet Service Provider (ISP), language and other characteristics about online users based solely on their IP addresses

Their website also makes the same claims.